# Migration CakePHP 1.2 -> 1.3 : Problem loading models

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-1.3

I'm currently migrating a working app from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3.  Most things seem fine so far, except it appears that some models are not being loaded correctly in the app_controller.php.  For example I have included the model 'message_thread.php' with

```
var $uses = array('MessageThread');
```

but when I try and

```
debug($this->MessageThread);
```

I get the error

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: ProjectsController::$MessageThread [APP/app_controller.php, line 415]
```

The model is also loaded in the Projects controller, but I don't see why this is being called on a simple debug($this->MessageThread); call.

This problem has broken previously working code, so that

```
$this->MessageThread->create();
```

result in the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in
```

any ideas?

Comment: I had similar issues in 1.3 when also declaring $uses in both AppModel and ConcreteModel.

Comment: @sibidiba : $uses array has to be used in controller .

Comment: Yeah, try adding `$uses` in your controller, not in AppController.

Comment: using '$uses' array is not a good practice.Always use relation or loadModel for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load models into all controllers in the app controller as you are trying.  Are you using php5?  If so, tru using public instead of var when defining the array to see if the array is I heartier properly.

```
public $uses = array('MessageThread');
```

As per the other comments, it is best if you load models in each specific controller. Please let me know if this works.